# Confusion over else...if vs regular if

Tags: javascript

I am a brand new programming hobbyist. I decided to start with JavaScript because I am interested in Web Development. Working through some classes I have encountered something that really confuses me. What is the purpose of "else...if" when it seems that multiple "ifs" do the same thing. I've really tried to find this answer before I posted here. I've worked out several tests in the Chrome console. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Welcome, it's helpful to post a specific example of code you're having issues with.

Comment: With multiple `if` statements, more than one of them could be executed. With `else if`, only one of the blocks will be executed.

Comment: @AndyRay instead of "only one" I'd say "at most one"

Comment: `else` is "not in any of the cases before", so e.g. `if (x === 2) {} else if (x % 2 === 0) { /* x is even but not two */ }`. Such things are frequent, and it's easier to write than repeating all the conditions.

Comment: Can you just use multiple ifs? Sure, but the code is inefficient because it will have to check each if statement.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a difference when multiple conditions might hold.
For example:

```
if (x) { do thing 1 }
if (y) { do thing 2 }
```

will do *both* thing 1 and thing 2 if x and y are both true.
But

```
if (x) { do thing 1 }
else if (y) { do thing 2 }
```

will do *only* thing 1 if x is true, even if y is also true.
It will do y only if y is true and x is false.